# \n not working in alert typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Why is it that newline is not working in alert typescript? I've tried \\n, \r\n, \n but it doesn't work here are my codes that i wanted to put a newline,

```
   else if(isVerified == true && localStorage.getItem("verified") == "false"){

  this.alert.create({
    title: "You are almost there! ",
    message: "As of the moment you can only \n receive items (Receiver) from other users of PlsDala. \n To Add a travel plan and deliver items (Courier) , and \n avail a delivery service (Receiver)." +"\r\n" + "Please prepare: \n\n\n One (1) valid ID \n\n One (1)  copy of your Birth Certificate \n Two (2) latest copy of your 2x2 picture \n For your personal interview at this Address: \n You can call this number () for more details",
    inputs: [{
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Don\'t show this again',
      handler: data=>{
        localStorage.setItem("verified", ""+data.checked+"");
      }
    }], 
    buttons: [{
      text: "Ok",
      role: 'cancel',
    }]
  }).present();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use html syntax in the message field of your alert, try using <br /> instead of newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

> Depends on where you display the alert. Its not a typescript error
>   because the displaying of error is not done by typescript. You have to
>   use the newline character according to where you are displaying the
>   alert.

`\n` works in linux consoles. But, if you are displaying it in a web page, use the corresponding newline character instead, ie `<br/>`